# It is possible to set scrollbar thumb 100px from the begining

Tags: css

The only thing I found is static margin of the scrollbar thumb, but I want scrollbar initial state to be with a padding, like this:
[image]

But it should have an ability for going back, like this:

[image]

Please do not advice me to use js, I want to do it with css only. So it simply should be scrollbar, but with intial space from the begining. Is it possible?

Comment: I doubt it. Also, what have you tried yourself? Also, you are putting way to much effort into customizing a standard element that you should preferably not change for usability.

Comment: You could save everyone a lot of scrolling if you trimmed your screenshots of the scrollbars to the first 110 pixels... Also, "is it possible" is unlikely to be what you're really asking. You're asking "how can I do it". Trust me, people will let you know if it's not possible.

Comment: @somethinghere I tried and searched in google, but nothing is working

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you